# OpenStreetMap - determine if circle intersect road

Tags: geometry, openstreetmap, intersect

How can i determine if a given point(lat,lon) is in a road segment or not?

Further explanation on what i want to achieve :

I have a reference point(lat1,lon1). I determine a circle with a radius of 30 meters, and a center (lat1, lon1). if want to know if this circle intersect roads.

do i have to use more than the OSM DB (wms service to get feature and compute intersection?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that with the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). You'll need the [around](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Around)-query. The syntax looks like the following:

```
way(around:<radius>,<lat>,<lng>);
```

…or take a look at this [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/rl).